# Jest testing with mount and React's context API

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I am trying to test my context API implementation with jest using mount but I am getting an error

*TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined*

I have tried various technique to pass the context data to the component during testing but so far no success.

**ApplicationContext.js**

```
import React from 'react'

const AppContext = React.createContext()
export default AppContext
```

**MyComponent.js** file

```
render () {
  return (
    <AppContext.Consumer>
      {context => (
        { context.state.user === SUPER_USER
          ? <Dashboard></Dashboard>
          : <Info></Info>
      )}
    </AppContext.Consumer>
  )
}
```

Methods I tried

```
//version 1
const wrapper = mount(<AppContext.Provider context={{ state: { user: SUPER_USER } }}><ActivityDisplay {...props} /></AppContext.Provider>)
  instance = wrapper.instance()
})

//version 2
wrapper = mount(<HomePage {...props} />, {
  context: { state: { user: SUPER_USER } },
})

//version 3
wrapper = mount(<HomePage {...props} />, {
  AppContext: {
    Consumer: { user: SUPER_USER }
  }
})

afterAll(() => {
  wrapper.unmount()
})

it('should display dashboard when user is SUPER_USER', () => {
  //do my assertions here
})
```

When I debug the app with above test code, context is always undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Provider accepts a value prop not a context prop. https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextprovider

AppContext.Provider value={{ state: { user: SUPER_USER } }}